# could not find application icon in Simulator BlackBerry java plugin for Eclipse Run

Tags: java, eclipse, blackberry

I've installed BlackBerry Plugin for Eclipse. Create simple Hello World blackberry application. Execute "Run as BlackBerry Application".
But in simulator window I couldn't see application running. Could not fine corresponding icon in Applications folder.

But if I click blackberry menu button from application folder and chose "Switch application" I do see my application icon in shortlist and could switch to it.

That is really strange.

Using JDK for OS5. (I do need to run this on BB 5,6,7)

Comment: If you can't see it running probably it is not compiling, and the one already in the simulator might be from a previous (successful) compilation. As for the icon, perhaps you are looking in the wrong folder.

Comment: Try looking in the **Downloads** folder, instead of **Applications**.  Yes, that one I think got us all at some point in the past :)